# Значит vs. означает

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, лексика, синонимы

> "Надо браться за дело, закатав рукава" значит, что(,) несмотря на все трудности, препятствия, к делу, к работе нужно подходить ответственно.

Какое слово — *значит* или *означает* — лучше употребить в приведенном контексте? Нормально ли построено предложение? Обособляется ли в данном случае оборот с *несмотря на*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Возможна такая форма предложения**: Браться за дело засучив рукава — значит выполнять  работу усердно, старательно, энергично, не останавливаясь перед любыми трудностями и препятствиями.

Здесь ЗНАЧИТ является не глаголом, а связкой между подлежщим и сказуемым в простом предложении.

**И замечание по содержанию:** данный фразеологизм обозначает именно энергичную и оперативную работу, но, по-моему не имеет прямого отношения к ответственности.

**Дополнение**

**1) Проверка грамматики и пунктуации заданного предложения**

"Надо браться за дело засучив рукава" значит, что, несмотря на все трудности, препятствия, к делу, к работе нужно подходить ответственно.

Всё в пределах нормы, глагол "значить" мне кажется более уместным, распространенный оборот с предлогом НЕСМОТРЯ НА в данной позиции однозначно обособляется, но фразеологический оборот желательно использовать в классической форме и не обособлять.

**2) О глаголах значить и означать**

Из словаря: **ОЗНАЧАТЬ**, нсв. что. 1. Иметь тот или иной смысл, значение (о словах, знаках, жестах). Что означает ваше молчание? Многоточие означает пропуск текста. **ЗНАЧИТЬ,**  1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. Иметь какой-л. смысл, **означать** (о словах, знаках, жестах и т. п.). Имя Виктор значит победитель. Кивок головы значит согласие. Поднятая вверх рука дрессировщика значила стоять. Изумлённый взгляд слушателя значил, что он не согласен. /

Глаголы считаются синонимичными, но по факту употребления могут различаться, например: (1) Многоточие означает пропуск текста. Или: (2) Многоточие значит пропуск текста. Первый вариант **"означать"** кажется более корректным: в этом случае мы как бы "даем определение" значению знака (приставка О!), а во втором случае **"значить"** "считываем" это значение.

**В заданном предложении** (глагол значить) автор скорее озвучивает/считывает информацию, которая является его убеждением в соответствием с жизненным опытом.

Comment: Это из сочинения ОГЭ по тексту Лиханова (про молодую учительницу); мб, контекст позволяет такое значение определить? И да, у Лиханова в тексте пунктуация как в цитате.

Answer (score 1):

> Нормально ли построено предложение?

Если смысл передан правильно, то в пределах нормы. Хотя от высокого стиля далеко.

> Какое слово — значит или означает — лучше употребить в приведенном контексте?

Тут надо уточнить. Мне непонятно, кому принадлежит изречение в кавычках.

Сравните:

*Если тебе сказали, что надо браться за дело закатав рукава, то надо браться...*

*Выражение "надо браться за дело закатав рукава" означает...*

В первом случае "значит" вообще смысла не добавляет, является ввожным и замена на означает невозможна. Да оно и само по себе не нужно. Даже как вводное.

Во втором значит синонимично "означет".

> Обособляется ли в данном случае оборот с несмотря на?

Если обособляется, то по любому - с двух сторон. А так да, лучше обособить, фраза длинная и распространенная.

(+++) 
"Закатав рукава" считаю допустимым вариантом для "засучив".

Comment: Это предложение из сочинения формата ОГЭ, в котором комментируется цитата из текста-задания. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, фразеологизм звучит как "засучив рукава" и означает "усердно, очень старательно, ответственно".

*Несмотря на* здесь является производным предлогом, равным по значению "вопреки", обособляется вместе с зависимыми словами ("несмотря на все трудности, препятствия").

Глаголы "означать" и "значить" являются производными от имени существительного *знак.*  Производный глагол "значить" выражал значения: "отмечать знаком, приметой" и `иметь знак' ("История слов" В. В. Виноградов). Они считаются синонимичными как по лексическому, грамматическому значению, так и по употреблению в речи.

Я бы только не обособляла "засучив рукава", так как это фразеологизм, и из двух абсолютно равнозначных синонимов "дело" и "работа" оставила бы один любой.

*"Надо браться за дело засучив рукава" означает, что, несмотря на все трудности и препятствия, к работе нужно подходить ответственно.*

Answer (score 0):

> Нормально ли построено предложение?

Отвечает акунинский Маса: "Доворьно дурацкая дорога". Версус: канцелярит, батенька. И кто сказал, что некий Лиханов писатель, м? Это Акунин писатель, хоть и называет себя кокетливо "беллетристом".

Но ежели всё цитата, какой у нас выбор - лексики ли, знаков ли? Мы можем только *обосновывать* предъявленное.

Предложение можно счесть правильно построенным, если представить, что некий не в меру любознательный пацанёнок-первоклашка успел спросить учительницу: а что такое - браться за дело, закатав рукава? это как?

Тяжко вздохнув, учительница отвечает, как положено учить говорить первоклашек - с повторением в ответе вопросительного предложения.

Ну вот и получилось у неё:

*"Надо браться за дело, закатав рукава" означает, что, несмотря на все трудности, препятствия, к делу, к работе нужно подходить ответственно.*

Выбираем глагол "означает" - потому что даём толкование фразеологизму, хоть бы и сдвинутому по фазе (что все присутствующие и отметили).

А от запятых у "несмотря на" куда ж деться? Это же не часть сказуемого в данном контексте...